# BiPredicate rules for Cardgame (Java)

Tags: java, rules

I have a task at University and I cannot really seem to get how I'm supposed to use the BiPredicate function without implementing the Bipredicate interface.
I have to use these lines of code and add to them without changing anything that is already there:

```
public static BiPredicate<Card, Card> sameValueRule()
public static BiPredicate<Card, Card> sameSuitRule()
public static BiPredicate<Card, Card> increasingValueRule()
public static BiPredicate<Card, Card> jokerRule(Card joker)()
```

Each Card has a suite and a value from 1-13. the Card.equals and .hashCode methods have been overwritten to return true if both the suite and value of the two cards are the same. The first and second rule are supposed to state that only cards with the same value/suite are are allowed to be played. Increasing Value only allows cards of higher value to be played while the jokerRule only allows cards equal to the joker card to be played.
I'm at a loss and have been sitting here for quite a while now. I hope someone can help me and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your teacher is using Java 8's new functional interfaces, he probably wants you to use Java 8's lambdas. [Here's a quick tutorial.](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html)

Comment: I will try this.  But I'm pretty sure our automated correction program is not going to like it. While this mide lead to the same result the program often checks if we have used the symbols given in the task. If I understand Lambdas correctly I'd need to remove the brackets and replace them with an '=' to use them which might lead to the programm not finding the functions.